# Setting z-index of UITableView header

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit

Is there a way to set the zindex of a section header in UITableView? Currently I have a header that's slightly bigger than it should be so it can create a nice "layered" look with the rounded corners of the first cell.

The only other option I've found is to cliptobounds, but that leaves a small gap and the ends of the header abruptly end instead of flowing nicely under the first cell.

The ideal solution would be to push the header to the back of the view stack and allow the first cell to overlap it.

Answer (score 1):

```
headerView.layer.zPosition = 1 // to front
                           = -1 // to back
```

Also, if necessary it is possible to adjust z position of the cell view in the same manner.

In both cases, make sure that the table view scroll indicator is not overlapped.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but if anyone else runs into this issue, you can call:

```
[tableView sendSubviewToBack:headerView];
```